# React Material-UI Autocomplete - reset dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

We are building an autocomplete field in Material UI for our React project.  The goal is to have the dropdown list be build dynamically as part of a search function this part works as expected.  The issue becomes when the user does another search, the dropdown list has retained the previous dropdown list value.  The field itself is blank, as intended.  Our app is built as class components.

```
<Autocomplete
id="add-staff-user-search"
freeSolo
filterOptions={(options, state) => options}
size="small"
options={obj.state.addStaffModal.ldapUserList}
getOptionLabel={(option) => {
    const fullName = option.appUserFullName;
    if (fullName === undefined)
        return option;
    const userEmail = option.appUserEmail;
    const suffix = userEmail ? userEmail : option.upn;
    return (
        <div>
            <span>{fullName}</span>
            <span>{suffix}</span>
        </div>);
}}
onInput={(evt) => obj.handleSearchNameChange(evt)}
onChange={(evt, newValue) => {
    if (newValue && newValue.upn) {
        obj.selectUserH(newValue.upn);
    }
}}
renderInput={(params) =>
    <TextField {...params}
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder="first name last name"
        onKeyPress={(event) => {
            if (event.charCode === 13)
                event.preventDefault();
        }}
    />
} />
```

How do we go about resetting the getOptionLabel? We have tried doing a setState({ ldapUserList: [] }) code snippet at various points in the handleSearchNameChange function, but to no effect.

```
staffNameToAdd = '';
handleSeachNameChange = (evt) => {
    this.staffNameToAdd = evt.target.value;

    if ((this.staffNameToAdd.indexOf(",") > 0 || this.staffNameToAdd.indexOf(" ") > 0) && this.staffNameToAdd.length > 5) {
        const n = this.staffNameToAdd;
        var fName = "", lName = "";
        var arrName;
        if (this.staffNameToAdd.indexOf(",") > 0) {
            arrName = n.split(",");
            fName = arrName[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            lName = arrName[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        }
        else {
            arrName = n.split(" ");
            fName = arrName[0].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
            lName = arrName[1].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        }

        if (fName.length === 0 || lName.length === 0) return false;

        const r = solicitationService.getUserFromLdapByFirstLastNames(fName, lName);
        r.then((d) => {
            if (!d) return;
            var add = Object.assign({}, this.state.addStaffModal);
            add.openUserList = true;
            add.ldapUserList = d.data;
            this.setState({ addStaffModal: add })
            //console.log(this.state.addStaffModal);
        });

    } else {
        var theModel = Object.assign({}, this.state.addStaffModal);
        theModel.ldapUserList = [];
        this.setState({ addStaffModal: theModel });
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/,

The event that fires when input value changes calls `onInputChange` not `onInput`, try to handle this event and maintain `inputValue` state.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @SeaOfDreams.  I realized, after reviewing your answer, that I needed to refine the question - the field itself is fine, it is the dropdown list, within the getOptionLabel param, that is the issue.

Comment: ended up resolving it with the following:

added this as a param for autocomplete: onInputChange={(evt) => obj.handleOnInputNameChange(evt)}

added this function:
` handleOnInputNameChange = (evt) => {
        let value = evt.target.value;
        if (value == undefined) {
            var theModel = Object.assign({}, this.state.addStaffModal);
            theModel.ldapUserList = [];
            this.setState({ addStaffModal: theModel });
        }
    }`

Thanks!